# How to avoid complexTypes in XML Schema

Tags: xml, schema, xsd

It says here ( http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/798 ) that you should avoid using complexTypes in XML Schema.  How to I use Attributes without complex types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you link to is misleading. I think it advises you to not use *named* (top-level) complexTypes. But you still have to use complexTypes (within an element declaration) if you want to use attributes (the article says: "consider this as a place holder"). Personally I think there's nothing wrong with named complexTypes, but it's true you don't need them to start with XML schemas.